# How to apply the else if condition into the LINQ query.?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a list of subjects 'subjectList' I want to get the value based on two conditions like if subjectValue!=null then select subjectValue else if the subject is isDefault=true then select subjectDefaultCode, I have written an individual LINQ query for both condition that but I am not getting how to apply both the condition in a single query.?
Have a look.

`string subjectValueDropDown = string.Empty;`

First condition.

`subjectValueDropDown = string.Join(",", subjectList.Where(x => x.SubjectValue != null).Select(k => k.SubjectValue).ToArray());`

Second condition.

`subjectValueDropDown = string.Join(",", subjectList.Where(x => x.IsDefault == true).Select(k => k.subjectDefaultCode).ToArray());`

Possbilities:

```
Subject1 SubjectValue=null , isDefault=false
Subject2 SubjectValue=Maths , isDefault=false
Subject3 SubjectValue=null , isDefault=true
Subject4 SubjectValue=null , isDefault=false
```

**In this situation or another situation where any of the subject have SubjectValue!=null then I don't want the isDefault condition to get executed.**

Thanks in advance.

**Updated:**
Output should be same as op of below query:

```
subjectValueDropDown = string.Join(",", subjectList.Where(x => x.SubjectValue != null).Select(k => k.SubjectValue).ToArray());
if(subjectValueDropDown==""){
    subjectValueDropDown = string.Join(",", subjectList.Where(x => x.IsDefault == true).Select(k => k.subjectDefaultCode).ToArray());
}
```

Is it possible to merge both the query into a single query to get the expected output.

Comment: `subjectList` is a list of what class? I want to see it.

Comment: @IvanKhorin It's a Model class. ```(List<SubjectValuesViewModel> subjectList)``` this is what i have into the method parameter.

Comment: I struggling to understand the question, could you make clear what you are trying to do? Is this a linq query or an entity framework query you can't translate to appropriate syntax?

Comment: @FilipCordas It's a simple we got subjectList from a stored procedure and passing that list into this method where I have to get the subjectValueDropDown.

Comment: How does `Subject 1` differ from  `Subject 4`? Can please share with us the definition of the `SubjectValuesViewModel` structure?

Comment: Your final output code doesn't reflect your problem description - please correct the code or the description to be correct. Your initial code also doesn't match the description - it does not implement the else properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it was tested in Visual Studio and values are the same as in your update:

```
subjectValueDropDown = string.Join(",", 
subjectList
.Where(x =>
                (x.SubjectValue != null)
                || (x.SubjectValue == null && x.IsDefault)
    
    ).Select(k =>
       k.SubjectValue != null? k.SubjectValue : k.SubjectDefaultCode
      )
      .OfType<string>()
  .ToArray());
```

Comment: I have to select different column values in both the condition in first I want to select SubjectValue and in the second I want to select the subjectDefaultCode column value.

Comment: It's not what he want

Comment: What type are SubjectValue and subjectDefaultCode ?

Comment: @Sergey SubjectValue and subjectDefaultCode both are of type string.

Comment: @TauFeeQ I updated my answer. It works in my VS2019.

Comment: Why are you testing `SubjectValue` twice? (Logic dictates after `!= null` and `||` you know `SubjectValue == null` so that test is wasted: just do `x.SubjectValue !=null || x.IsDefault`.) Don't switch from `x` to `k` - better still use `s` instead of `x` both times. What is the purpose of `OfType` in your answer? Why use `ToArray` when there is an overload for `String.Join` that accepts `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Everything is for the pourpouse in my query . If you change something it will not be working properly.What is difference if SelectVlaue tests twice. It passed thousands tests already from Db to this code

Comment: I had spent my Sunday making some research and   creating this code but I don't  even get  thank you for this.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Game
{
    class Subject
    {
        public string SubjectValue { get; set; }
        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
        public string subjectDefaultCode = "Defauult code.";
    }

    class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var subjectList = new List<Subject>
            {
                new Subject
                {                    
                    IsDefault = false,
                },
                new Subject
                {
                    SubjectValue = "Maths",
                    IsDefault = false,
                },
                new Subject
                {
                    IsDefault = false,
                },
                new Subject
                {
                    IsDefault = false,
                },
            }; 

            var ubjectValueDropDown = string.Join(",", subjectList.Where(x => x.SubjectValue is not null || x.IsDefault)
                .Select(x => 
                {
                    if (x.SubjectValue is not null)
                        return x.SubjectValue;
                    
                    if (x.IsDefault)
                        return x.subjectDefaultCode;

                    return "";
                }));     
        }
    }
}
```